# Which is faster: "null == myObject" or "myObject == null"?

Tags: java, .net, null, operator-precedence, control-structure

In both Java and .Net, I've heard that using null first `if (null == myObject)` is more performant than using the object first `if (myObject == null)`. While I think this is probably true, I'm not certain and would like to know from SO users. Personally, I think it reads better if the object is referenced first, but if there's any performance gain by using null first, I'll opt for that instead.

Comment: It's extremely unlikely the difference, if there is any, does matter.

Comment: In Java they both fail to compile if you put = by mistake.

Comment: @QuentinUK unless you compare a Boolean

Comment: I see now it's really only a result how C programmers use to code to avoid mistakes since this coding practice was suggested to my by a former C programmer.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen in that case the first can be used to avoid accidental mistakes, just as it's common in C to put the constant on the left.

Comment: @johntrepreneur Java was deliberately designed to resemble C.  Java references work quite differently from C pointers, so C habits for pointers do not carry over to references.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen right, so it's just an old habbit (by some) and has no added value in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're exactly the same. If there was a difference, any compiler would make the swap as there is absolutely no functional difference.

Comment: I know they're the same functionally, but I was curious about performance.

Answer (score 5):

Surprise, they compile differently in Java:

```
if (myObject == null);
if (null == myObject);
```

compiles to

```
 8 aload_1
 9 ifnonnull 12 (+3)
12 aconst_null
13 aload_1
14 if_acmpne 17 (+3)
```

(This was compiled using `javac 1.6.0_24`.)

Putting the object reference first results in two instructions, and putting the `null` first results in three instructions.  On that basis, `if (myObject == null)` *might* be faster.

However, as Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen points out, when using a JIT compiler the number of bytecode instructions doesn't mean much, as the bytecode will be converted to native code before execution anyway.  And even if there is a performance difference, I doubt it would be measurable.

Comment: You cannot decide execution speed from the number of byte codes if your JVM uses a JIT compiler.

Comment: +1 On mentioning the bytecode. The same reason string concatenation is less efficient with the `+` operator then using a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Ah good point.  I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @matts you stated "And even if there is a performance difference, I doubt it would be measurable". Wouldn't larger objects then take longer if its evaluating the whole object as opposed to small object just to see if its null? I would think it would short circuit out of checking the whole object if it knows it just needs to see if its null.

Comment: @johntrepreneur Well I'm no expert, but I don't think the size of the object makes a difference here.  When used with objects, the `==` operator compares the object references, similar to pointers in other languages.  It doesn't actually evaluate the object's value.  Also, an object itself cannot *be* null, only a variable (which can point at an object) may be null.

Comment: In C# I had the same before adding a fake istruction between the two tests. Without that fake op the bytecode emitted is optimized to reuse the null value already in the registers.

Comment: @matts ahh you're right good point (+1). I guess I'm mixing up the different languages I'm using it in. In Java, yes; in C# == is overloaded to allow an equality check although I think that's just syntactic sugar so it's probably the same as Java. However, in javascript you can use the == operator to check for equality although now I'm getting outside the scope of my original question since I didn't ask for this language, but I'm still curious as this practice can be applied there too.

Comment: @matts just to summarize, if the == operator is checking for equality like in javascript, then it will evaluate the objects content and traversing a bigger object will take more time if it doesn't know ahead of time it's just looking for null (i.e. null on left).

Comment: @johntrepreneur in Java the `==` operator isn't overloaded to compare objects' content for equality.  You have to use the `equals` method for that.  When used on two separate objects, `==` evaluates to `false`, even if they have equal content.  For instance, `new String("test") == new String("test")` should evaluate to `false`, although `new String("test").equals(new String("test"))` will evaluate to `true`.  Not sure if that answers your question

Comment: @matts thanks but no that's Java 101 basics. No, my question was in reference to **Javascript** where you [can check for equality with ==](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp) and since that is the case, how does it work with bigger objects? More specifically, if the object is on the left of the conditional (in Javascript) `if (myObject == null)`, will it read the whole object first and then do the null check? as opposed to having `if (null = myObject)` knowing it just needs to know if it's null and short circuiting out of reading the object as soon as it realizes it's not null.

Comment: @johntrepreneur Ohhh, sorry I misunderstood; I have no idea about JavaScript, but I *think* `null` is a constant and I would *guess* that since many JavaScript engines these days also use a JIT, they would optimize out a full object comparison.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect Java to generate exactly the same bytecode for both versions (probably the [`ifnull` bytecode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)), so use whichever reads better to you.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say for Java but I will be very surprised if there, it is different.
In a C# sample I write

```
void Main()
{
    object o = new object();

    if(null == o)
        Console.WriteLine("o is null");

    // to force a reload of the registers
    o = new object();

    if(o == null)
        Console.WriteLine("o is null");
}
```

the resulting IL code is

```
IL_0000:  newobj      System.Object..ctor
IL_0005:  stloc.0     // o
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     // o
IL_0007:  brtrue.s    IL_0013
IL_0009:  ldstr       "o is null"
IL_000E:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0013:  newobj      System.Object..ctor
IL_0018:  stloc.0     // o
IL_0019:  ldloc.0     // o
IL_001A:  brtrue.s    IL_0026
IL_001C:  ldstr       "o is null"
IL_0021:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
```

NO DIFFERENCE AT ALL